# Run EF Migrations with Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-devops, .net-5

I want to run EF migrations from Azure DevOps.

For dev environment I use update-database in Visual Studio/Package Manager Console but in DevOps the only option I found is to generate a migration script, script that is corrupt when I have SQL code in my migrations like this one:

```
       migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
                CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunc] 
                (
                    @param2 int, 
                    @param1 int
                ) 
                RETURNS FLOAT 
                AS 
                BEGIN 
                DECLARE @result AS FLOAT
                    --content
                RETURN ISNULL(@result, 0);

                END");
```

I tried also with some extensions but without success.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bendayconsulting.build-task&ssr=false#overview

The command I use now in DevOps is:

```
migrations script --startup-project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test.Web/Test.Web.csproj --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test.DAL/Test.DAL.csproj --context TestContext -i -o migration.sql
```

Can I bypass the script generation and directly apply the 'update-database' command in DevOps?

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet ef database update --project ...`?

Comment: Yes, but without success. I need to update database in the release step because I have multiple environments and I didn't manage to execute the command without the source code (I have to execute the command starting from publish). I wonder if there is some standard way to achieve this, some kind of guideline from Microsoft

Comment: You should write migrations that generate correct scripts.  Sometimes you must wrap your DDL in dynamic SQL to work around EF's inability to generate correct scripts to prevent batch parsing errors or to ensure required batch isolation for some DDL.